# How To send data form Controller to other Model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I create view for register and send data to controller

```
//app::import('Model','Myprofile');
Class MembersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Members';
    var $helpers = array('Form', 'Session');
    var $uses = array('Myprofile'); //

    function register() {
        //$myprofile = new Myprofile();
        if (!empty($this - > data)) {
            $this - > Member - > create();
            if ($this - > Member - > save(($this - > data['Member']['username']), ($this - > data['Member']['password'])) && $this - > Myprofile - > save(($this - > data['Myprofile']['name']), ($this - > data['MyProfile']['address']), ($this - > data['Myprofile']['phonenumber']))) {
                $this - > redirect('index');
            }
        } else {

            $this - > Session - > setFlash('failed');
        }

    }
```

I want to send data form memberscontroller to Myprofile Model
I try to use

```
$use = array('Myprofile');
```

i got

```
Undefined property: MembersController::$Member
```

when I use

```
//app::import('Model','Myprofile');
//$myprofile = new Myprofile()
```

i got

```
Undefined property: MembersController::$Myprofile
```

I do not know the right way or not
There is also another way to fix my problem
Thank for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `$uses` array, make sure that you have the current model included in that array as well. Otherwise the current model does not get included by default if you define a specific `$uses` array.

If `MyProfile` is related to `Member` you can access it via

```
$this->Member->MyProfile; //depends on associations
```

You can also use `App:import`

```
App:import('Model', array('Myprofile')); //loads the class
$myProfile = new MyProfile();
// OR
MyProfile::staticMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

The $uses array will only give you access to the models you specify in it.

If you'd commented out $uses, you would still have access to $this->Member model by default since you are in the Members controller.

Once you add another model to the $uses array, you must remember to include your initial model as well.

I've also found that in some cases, it's very useful to make sure that when you're doing something like that, you should specify your default model *FIRST*

```
var $uses = array( 'Member', 'Myprofile' );
```

Otherwise you might get unexpected results from actions like $this->paginate()

Comment: ้ำัhey
I followed the advice you guys
but I got 
Undefined property: MembersController::$Myprofile

Comment: Then the problem is likely in the code for your Myprofile model, either in it's class name or in it's file name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both models to your `$uses` array:

```
var $uses = array('Myprofile', 'Member');
```

Comment: ้ำัhey I followed the advice you guys but I got Undefined property: MembersController::$Myprofile

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$this->loadModel('Myprofile');` in your action.

and are you sure your model name is 'Myprofile' ?

you can even debug it to see if it return true or false. this will help you find if the model has been correctly instancieted.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke any public methods of related models in normal way. for eg

In Profile.php

```
function someMethod( $param = null ) {
    // some definition
}
```

From MembersController.php

```
function register ( ) {
    $this->Member->Profile->someMethod( $my_data_to_pass );    // if related
    /* if not related 
    $this->loadModel('Profile');
    $this->Profile->someMethod($my_data_to_pass);
    */
}
```

As a side note, if you ran into this situation for making urls more sensible, Please look into Router (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/router.html)